# getting strange values for pointer and a regular int

Tags: c++, c++11, compilation, heap-memory, stack-memory

I'm trying to learn about stack and heap at c++ and just started to print tests to learn how it's work.

I wrote this code:

```
`#include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 int main (){

 int a;
 int b;
 int *c;
 int *c2;
 int *d{new int};

 cout << &a << "   a= " << a << endl;
 cout << &b << "   b= " << b << endl;
 cout << &c << "   c= " << c << endl;
 cout << &c2 << "  c2= " << c2 << endl;
 cout << &d << "   d= " << d << endl;

 delete d;

 return 0;

 }
```

the output is:

> 0x7ffefad88d00   a= 124
>
> 0x7ffefad88d04   b= 0
>
> 0x7ffefad88d08   c= 0
>
> 0x7ffefad88d10   c2= 0x400b20
>
> 0x7ffefad88d18   d= 0xec9c20

There are 3 things I do not understand:

1. why a value is 124?
2. why c value is 0 and not a pointer like c2 that have the same syntax?
3. why c size is just 2 byts and not 4?

Comment: Since you haven't initialised `a` and triy to print its value, this is undefined behaviour - so anything could happen. The size of an `int` varies depending on the compiler.

Comment: thanks, but i didnt initialised b as well... why he didnt get the complier value?

Comment: 0 is a perfectly acceptable random number

Comment: o.k. thanks... what about c?you know why its happend?

Answer (score 2):

`a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and the value of `*d` are uninitialized, reading them is [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior). Anything can happen, nobody can predict the value of those variables. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior-in-c) for more information.

About the printout of the pointers, many implementations trim leading 0s. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190708/c-pointer-on-64-bit-machine). If I try to print out the values of pointers in Visual Studio 2015, I get the leading zeros.

Comment: And? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546620/operator-new-initializes-memory-to-zero

Answer (score 1):

> why a value is 124?

`a` is uninitialized, hence reading it will give you unpredictable value. Reading uninitialized non-static local variable is UB. But, uninitialized global and static variables are initialized with 0 at compile time and reading them is fine.

> why c value is 0 and not a pointer like c2 that have the same syntax?

`c` is also uninitialized, so what it points to is also undefined as mentioned above. It is a pointer like `c2`, but it points to `NULL` (which is 0).

> why c size is just 2 bytes and not 4?

`c` size of a pointer is architecture and/or compiler dependent. In this case `c` occupied 8 bytes. subtract the address of `c` from the address of `c2`.

`0x7ffefad88d10 - 0x7ffefad88d08 = 0x000000000008` these are hexadecimal values not decimal.

So, `c` is actually a pointer like `c2` and occupies same space in the memory.